# Is there any correlation between forecasting errors from forecasting done at different origins?

Tags: correlation, forecasting, expected-value, covariance, error

Let $\ e_{T+l|T} = Z_{T+l} - \hat{Z}_{T}(l)$ be the forecasting error $\ l$-steps ahead when the forecasting origin is time $\ T$.

Now, let $\ e_{T+l-j|T} = Z_{T+l-j} - \hat{Z}_{T-j}(l)$ be the forecasting error $\ l$-steps ahead when the forecasting origin is time $\ T-j$.

> Is there any correlation between them?

I know $\rho_{xy} = \large{\frac{cov(x,y)}{\sigma_{x}.\sigma_{y}}}$. Following this, I can write:

$\ cov(x,y) = \mathbb{E(xy)} - \mathbb{E(x)}.\mathbb{E(y)}$ [1], where $\mathbb{E(.)}$ is the expected value of (.).

Knowing that

$\mathbb{E}(e_{T+i|T}) = \mathbb{E}(Z_{T+i}) - \mathbb{E}(\hat{Z}_{T}(i)) $

$\mathbb{E}(e_{T+i|T}) = \hat{Z}_{T+i} - \hat{Z}_{T}(i)) = 0$

[1] becomes

$\ cov(x,y) = \mathbb{E(xy)}$

This led to:

$\ cov(e_{T+l|T}, e_{T+l-j|T}) = \mathbb{E}[(Z_{T+l} - \hat{Z}_{T}(l)) . (Z_{T+l-j} - \hat{Z}_{T-j}(l))]$

But after I expanded the product, I didn't know where to go. 
Any input will be appreciated.